# Converting UnityScript code to C#: What is the alternative for .ToBuiltin?

Tags: unity, c#, unityscript

I'm trying to convert this code from UnityScript (Unity's version of JavaScript) to C#:

```
var polys = new Array(); // array to collect vertex locations
polys.Push((scanpoint + padding) + Vector2(0.5, 0.5) * Pixel_vs_Unit_Scale);
var poly:Vector2[] = polys.ToBuiltin(Vector2);
```

I converted the first two lines like so, with no errors:

```
var polys = new List<Vector2>();
polys.Add((scanpoint + padding) + new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f) * Pixel_vs_Unit_Scale);
```

But when I try to adapt the last line like this:

```
Vector2[] poly = polys.ToBuiltin(Vector2);
```

I get two errors:

> ToBuiltin does not exist.

And also an error on the `Vector2` inside the `()`:

> Vector2 is a type which is not valid in the given context.

How can I convert this code to C# correctly?

Answer (score 5):

In Unity's JavaScript implementation (sometimes called UnityScript), [there are two types of array](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Array.html): JavaScript-style arrays, which have no particular type or length, and "Builtin" (native .NET arrays), which have a specific type and length.

In C#, we usually prefer to work with statically typed variables, so the usual equivalents we'd use would be:

- Generic Lists (`List<SomeType>`) if we want to be able to grow & shrink the collection dynamically
- Typed Arrays (`SomeType[]`) if we want to work with a fixed-size collection.

A list can produce a fixed-size typed array copy of its current contents with the `.ToArray` method. So, we can translate your code like so:

```
var polys = new List<Vector2>();
polys.Add((scanpoint+padding)+Vector2(0.5,0.5)*Pixel_vs_Unit_Scale);
var poly = polys.ToArray();
```

But this is a little silly - `poly` in this case will only ever contain that one item - we don't need the dynamically-sized intermediate to build it up. So unless we're reusing `polys` later in the code, we might as well define the `poly` array directly and then assign that one item to it:

```
var poly = new Vector2[1];
poly[0] = (scanpoint+padding)+Vector2(0.5,0.5)*Pixel_vs_Unit_Scale;
```

or even shorter:

```
var poly = new Vector2[]{(scanpoint+padding)+Vector2(0.5,0.5)*Pixel_vs_Unit_Scale};
```